Error while launching turtlebot3 in Gazebo 11.10.2
$ ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/user123/.ros/log/2024-10-27-13-07-32-839396-user123-Aspire-V5-571-8729
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_burger.urdf
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_burger.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [8730]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [8732]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [8734]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [8736]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.103455099] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.103860879] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.103915759] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.103958969] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.104000390] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.104041247] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1730014657.104077200] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730014658.587613118] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730014658.589259810] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730014658.591967985] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730014658.593402221] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730014660.358766422] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014660.951719160] [turtlebot3_imu]: <initial_orientation_as_reference> is unset, using default value of false to comply with REP 145 (world as orientation reference)
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730014661.347388830] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [burger]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.526877604] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 separation set to [0.160000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.527039410] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 diameter set to [0.066000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.531173299] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Subscribed to [/cmd_vel]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.540181462] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Advertise odometry on [/odom]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.550585125] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Publishing odom transforms between [odom] and [base_footprint]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 8736]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.593056255] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_left_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1730014661.593220617] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_right_joint]
[gzclient-2] gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:728: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::rendering::Camera; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type = gazebo::rendering::Camera*]: Assertion px != 0' failed.
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 8732, exit code -6, cmd 'gzclient'].
